# Function continuity and neighborhoods

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I have a function $g(x)$ that is continuous at point $x_0$. Assuming that $g(x_0) > \frac{1}{2}$, how would I show that there exists some neighborhood of $x_0$ such that $g(x) > \frac{1}{2}$ for all $x$ in that neighborhood?

Since $g(x)$ is continuous, I tried using

$\forall \varepsilon > 0 \text{ } \exists \text{ }  \delta > 0 \text{ s.t. } \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \text{ }  |x - x_0 | < \delta \implies |g(x) - g(x_0)| < \varepsilon$

along with a particular choice for $\varepsilon$ to force $g(x) > \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Apply the definition of continuity for $\epsilon=g(x_0)-1/2>0$

Answer (score 1):

Take $\epsilon = g(x_0)-1/2$. By continuity you have that $\exists \delta>0$ s.t. $g(B(\delta,x_0)) \subseteq B(\epsilon,g(x_0))$ then $B(\delta,x_0)$ is your desired neighborhood.